# Expected break before case error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am bringing some old code to modern JavaScript. I am now using Dreamweaver (was working in BBEdit) and it throws a lot of errors. The code is working, but it does not mean is a good code or will keep working in near future. Thought PHP is more clear about old practices the will be deprecated and stop working, with JavaScript I don't have this control. So the switch statement is like this today:

```
switch(property) {
  case "value1":
    dosomething...
    break;
  case "value2":
  case "value3":
    dootherthing...
}
```

Dreamweaver trow the error because it must be a break before case value3. However, in many cases I do several process based in the same property. Sometimes the process is the same for two values at that step of the code.
As Dreamweaver does not separates warnings from alerts or errors, I don't know if this is a bad practice or it will generate error in the browser soon. So my first question - is this actually an error?
Should I change this practice? What's the alternatives?

Comment: I haven't used Dreamweaver, but looks to me like it's just a configuration/linting issue? Check the documentation whether you can disable certain (useless) rules such as this one.

Comment: This is not a problem. The fact that you use `break` in a switch instead of it automatically breaking on each `case` keyword  means that you're supposed to be able to have multiple cases have the same code block without needing to repeat yourself. This is valid JavaScript, and is valid (with slight syntax changes) in most languages that use `switch`  statements

Comment: There is a way to disable the ruler check, I just want to disable it after be sure is not a real error, according with the last standards.

Comment: It's Dreamweaver's (poor) attempt to warn you of a possible error. Since you are doing it that way on purpose, the problem is Dreamweaver, not your code.